# Main window does not receive events after modal dialog is closed

Tags: android, c++, qt

My application was coded by QT and run on Android device.
On main windows of my application there is a button. When the user click on that button, my application will display a custom dialog (modal):

```
progressDialog = new QDialog(this);
...
progressDialog->setObjectName("processingDialog");
progressDialog->setModal(true);
progressDialog->show();
```

when the processing is finished, i want to hide that modal dialog and set focus back to main window:

```
progressDialog->close();
this->setFocus();
this->activateWindow();
```

But when i run on my Android device, when the modal dialog is closed, my main window does not received event (tab, touch, slide). When i tab on screen one time, my main window seem to be run normally

Please help me resolve this issue. Thanks you

I'm sorry if my question make you difficult to understand.

Comment: Why do you want to show a dialog with `show` method. It is prefferable to use `exec` for modal windows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android is a "single window" platform, this might be the source of your problems.

A possible solution would be to instead of a modal dialog you implement it in a different way, for example using a `QStackedWidget`, a stack view is widely used for mobile device "single window" applications.

Here is an example:

```
class W1 : public QWidget {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    W1(QWidget * p = 0) : QWidget(p) {
        QVBoxLayout * l = new QVBoxLayout(this);
        setLayout(l);
        QPushButton * b = new QPushButton("do work", this);
        l->addWidget(b);
        l->addSpacerItem(new QSpacerItem(1, 600));
        connect(b, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), parent(), SLOT(showBusyDialog()));
    }
};

class W2 : public QWidget {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    W2(QWidget * p = 0) : QWidget(p) {
        setAttribute(Qt::WA_OpaquePaintEvent, true);
        setAttribute(Qt::WA_NoSystemBackground);
        QVBoxLayout * l = new QVBoxLayout(this);
        setLayout(l);
        QLabel * lb = new QLabel("...working, please wait...", this);    
        l->addWidget(lb);
        l->setAlignment(lb, Qt::AlignCenter);
    }    
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent * ) {
        QPainter p(this);
        p.fillRect(rect(), QColor(0, 0, 0, 128));
    }
};

class MainW : public QStackedWidget {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MainW() {
        resize(300, 600);
        W1 * w1 = new W1(this);
        addWidget(w1);
    }
public slots:
    void showBusyDialog() {
        W2 * w2 = new W2(this);
        setCurrentIndex(addWidget(w2));
        QTimer::singleShot(2000, w2, SLOT(deleteLater()));
    }
};
```

The stack widget will initially load W1, when you press the "do work" button, a semi-transparent overlay dialog will show on top of it for 2 seconds, blocking interaction with the previous widget for the duration of the "work". After the work is done, the dialog will be closed.

BTW you might want to consider this approach even on systems which do support multiple windows, because modal dialogs are so "last century" - this way you can get uniform user experience across different platforms. Obviously the stack view can handle much more windows, dialogs, pages or whatever, if your application calls for it.

Comment: but i want it dispalyed as a dialog (smaller, and at center of other widget). how to the stacked widget do?

Comment: You can still do that with a stack view - the widget that will fill the screen can be made transparent and the dialog content can be centered in it. I have added a small example how to do it.

Comment: thanks you ddriver. I will try it and give me the result

Answer (score -2):

try          `progressDialog.dismiss();`
instead of .close();

Comment: QDialog and QWidget has no method name "Dismiss"?