# QT/QML , After Dialog is open , Back button not working on Android?

Tags: android, qt, qml

I can't find any solution for this.I have an dialog which has an TextArea and Ok and close buttons.When I opened the dialog , Then close it. Back button is not working on Android. Why ? My code is :

```
 Dialog {


    id: messagereject



    Connections
    {
        target:process
        ignoreUnknownSignals: true
        onSuccessrejectwo: {

            var task=stackView.get(0).currenttask;
            task.color="red";
            task.enabled=false;
            rejectreasontxt.text="";
        }
    }




  contentItem:ColumnLayout {
         id:rejectlay
        Layout.preferredHeight: rejectheadertxt.height+rejectreasontxt.height+dp(30)

        Layout.preferredWidth: rejectheadertxt.width+dp(100)

        spacing: dp(10)
      .......
    ......
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35777149/main-window-does-not-receive-events-after-modal-dialog-is-closed/35904458#35904458

Comment: Just go for a `StackView` instead of `Dialog`. Seems like at this point Android has some problem with returning from Qt dialogs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran into the very same problem myself today. In my app, I want to use a dialog with a TextField to let the user edit the title of some items.

The issue using Dialog in QML seems to be that even after the dialog is closed, it retains keyboard focus and hence captures the back button as well.

For me, the solution was to ensure that after the dialog has been closed (i.e. its `visible` property is set to `false`), active keyboard focus is handed back to the "main window":

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2

ApplicationWindow {
    id: mainWindow

    width: 200
    height: 150
    visible: true

    FocusScope {
        id: rootItem

        anchors.fill: parent

        Label {
            id: label

            text: qsTr("Hello World")
            anchors.centerIn: parent
        }

        Button {
            text: qsTr("Edit")
            anchors {
                right: parent.right
                bottom: parent.bottom
                margins: 10
            }

            onClicked: {
                edit.text = label.text;
                dialog.open();
                // Let the TextField gain keyboard focus. This also
                // means the main window no longer gets keyboard input
                // so from here on input (including the back button)
                // is handled by the dialog:
                edit.forceActiveFocus();
            }
        }
    }

    Dialog {
        id: dialog

        standardButtons: StandardButton.Ok | StandardButton.Cancel

        onAccepted: label.text = edit.text
        onVisibleChanged: {
            if (!visible) {
                // Force some item in the main window (in our case the "root item")
                // to gain active focus:
                rootItem.forceActiveFocus();
            }
        }

        TextField {
            id: edit
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That is right.forceActiveFocus function solve this problem